# ASP.NET Core Web API, how to add another Database provider (EF Core) for the new Controller dialog, like PostgreSQL?

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-web-api, controller, ef-core-3.1

I created a new ASP.NET Core Web API.
I try to add a controller in VS2022 by choosing "Add"-"Controller" to show the selection window.

I select: "Common-API", then "API Controller with actions, using Entity Framework".
Then I have this dialog where there is only SQL Server as "Database provider" and I can't select anything else.

[image]

**How to add PostgreSQL as a Database provider?**

In the meantime, why do I have to choose a Database provider if I already chosen a Database context which is already defined for a specific database engine?

Additional Info:

- I already have PostgreSQL dependencies:
  [image]

Answer (score 1):

To add PostgreSQL as a database provider for your ASP.NET Core Web API, you need to install the Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL package from the NuGet package manager.

You can follow these steps:

1. Right-click on the project in the Solution Explorer and choose "Manage NuGet Packages".
2. In the "Browse" tab, search for "Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" and install the latest version.
3. Once the package is installed, you should be able to select PostgreSQL as a database provider in the "Add Controller" dialog.
4. Optional: I recommend doing a clean, close, open, and rebuild when you're done to insure your IDE updates.

Regarding your second question, when you select a database provider in the "Add Controller" dialog, it is used to generate the scaffolded code for the controller and its actions. The selected provider is used to generate the necessary code for interacting with the database. Even though you have already defined a database context for a specific database engine, you still need to select a provider for the scaffolded code to be generated correctly.

Comment: Thanks but I already have all PostgreSQL dependencies, at least I think. I added additionnal information in my question to show what I 'm talking about. I think that it is a Microsoft bug or poor design, because it is grayed out (disable) and the connection is already defined in the DbContext. But it crashes with an error that means nothing so I was wondering if it ws due to that a missing PostgreSQL ref or command to do ?

Comment: That's so strange because I created a new web api on my machine and followed the steps in my answer and it worked no problem. I will keep looking for another answer for you.

Comment: Do you mean that you have PostgreSQL choice appearing in the comboBox ? Do you also have one or more DbContext shown?